# Projection equivalence

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, projection

Let $D\neq \emptyset \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, be a convex and closed set, and  $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $\overline{x}=P_{D}(x)$ if, and only if, \begin{equation*}
  \overline{x}\in D, \hspace{5mm} \langle y-\overline{x}, x-y\rangle \leq 0 \hspace{5mm}\text{for each}\hspace{2mm}y \in D.  
 \end{equation*}

Comment: Was your school assignment to post this on the internet for some random stranger to prove for you?

Comment: I @Mark L. Stone.  I find this affirmation in a text book and try prove but I can't prove this. So I ask for help. Among my attempts is $\|\overline{x}-x\|^{2}= \|\overline{x}-y+y-x\|^{2}= \|\overline{x}-y\|^{2} + 2\langle \overline{x}-x,y-x \rangle + \| y-x\|^{2}  $  but still $\langle \overline{x}-x,y-x \rangle \leq 0$ I don't understand how use this.